# Sample from the discrete triangular distribution

Tags: code-golf, random, restricted-complexity

Given an integer `n >= 1` as input, output a sample from the discrete triangular distribution over the integers `k`, for `1 <= k <= n` (`1 <= k < n` is also acceptable),
defined by `p(k) ∝ k`.

E.g. if `n = 3`, then `p(1) = 1/6`, `p(2) = 2/6`, and `p(3) = 3/6`.

Your code should take **constant expected time**, but you are allowed to ignore overflow, to treat floating point operations as exact, and to use a  PRNG (pseudorandom number generator).

You can treat your random number generator and all standard operations as constant time.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: An explanation of  *the discrete triangular distribution* with some test cases would be a lot clearer. Also *reasonable quality* isn't an objective criteria.

Comment: I suggest you remove the "reasonable quality" requirement for the PRNG. We usually assume that PRNG's are good enough; see for example [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10923/36398)

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain what you intend by "your code should take constant expected time".  Currently, answers seem to make different assumptions about whether a PRNG can be expected to run in constant time for all values of ```n``` in ```random_function(n)```, or whether this matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*-1 thanks to @emanresu A*

```
›℅‹$℅x
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLrihIXigLkk4oSFeCIsIiIsIjYiXQ==)

Comment: The : is unnecessary

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 37 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```javascript
n=>(Math.random()*n*-~n+1|0)**.5+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUxBasMwELzrFXvclWJFLuRQVAf6gPoDIQeR2K2CIgVZGErSft1ZYTKHmZ0ZZi9udtMp@1tpYjoPy9gtsdvjlys/Ort4TlckGWXzH1X7MCSl3im9e5glDAUidPC@EcDo@WxNxeqn4gpHnzm7X4ykRx8CGrJCjCljHXuujWX5gJ5FKYI7T/MwcTHyxor1zaFGDbRHpaz4E6cUpxQGHdI31lpf3Q1x3oAn6PZw4GsGCRhXUtASbOGtEvqX7eFIZJcn)

#### How?

We essentially pick a random integer in \$\left[1\dots\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right]\$ and then return the corresponding term in the sequence \$1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,\dots\$ (this is [A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024)).

A more readable form of the formula is:

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{2 \times\left\lfloor \operatorname{rand}()\times {n+1\choose 2}+1 \right\rfloor }+1/2\right\rfloor$$

leading to:

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{2 \times\lfloor \operatorname{rand}()\times n\times(n+1)/2+1 \rfloor }+1/2\right\rfloor$$

where \$\operatorname{rand}()\$ is assumed to return a random value drawn from the uniform distribution in the interval \$[0,1[\$.

Comment: `n=>(Math.random()*n*-~n+1)**.5+.5|0` avoids the second `floor`.

Comment: @Neil This may occasionally [return `n+1`](https://tio.run/##FYg7CoQwEED7nGLKfDQkhaBEDyMaRQkzMorNrnv1rKneZx/v8Zx4O64aaY45p3gBwgBdEGIhlqX5bWe7NrzWgy8w5TjnFXwEwER4Uoo20Sq5Askadf1D45XWtjG2@ToVxJPzHw).

Comment: My bad, but at least `+1` allows you to use `|0` instead of `&-1`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes

```python
lambda n:max(r(1,n),r(n))
from random import*
r=randrange
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXMSc5NSEhXyrHITKzSKNAx18jR1ijTyNDW50orycxWKEvNSgFRmbkF-UYkWV5EtSACI01OhBrgl2kYb6GDAWK60_CKFTIXMPAWwag1DAzDQtOJSUEiMTtMw1YzVtjXkKijKzCvRSNSEmLZgAYQGAA)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 60 bytes

```python
lambda n:max(divmod(randrange(n,n*n),n))
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3bXISc5NSEhXyrHITKzRSMsty81M0ihLzUoA4PVUjTydPK09TJ09TkyutKD9XASQDpDJzC_KLSrSgZrgl2kYb6GDAWK60_CKFTIXMPAWIYYYGYKBpxaWgkBidpmGqGatta8hVUJSZV6KRqAkxbcECCA0A)

### Picture:

```
   |  0  1  2  3  4  5
---+------------------
1  |  1  1  2  3  4  5
2  |  2  2  2  3  4  5
3  |  3  3  3  3  4  5
4  |  4  4  4  4  4  5
5  |  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
function(n)((1+4*runif(1)*n*(n+1))^.5-1)%/%2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7PbsIwDIfveQpLE1LSjpYgdgCpr4KUBgMerVcljjSevnM5jAsXfPO/3/elOUmibj4XjkI/bNlZ6@tdlQrT2XpXcWW59s4dm6@1d6t2ta39/AHxivEGckU4UdaIvizvUDLxBfxGC0gwhWWaDXd7Q91jbCT0A9ocpmm4W3@gz3/2t1tkVMG51lKby6h77Yx58oJoLqhdBmKIGi6BBfB3wih4AqERFbc1@Z4Fx2bpX8LoCdP7h5rKvfM1/wE)

`runif(1)` calculates a random number from the uniform distribution from zero to one.
We then need to work-out which triangularly-increasing interval this lies in.
So we multiply by the size of the full triangle (`n*(n+1)/2`) to get `c`, and solve the quadratic equation `x(x+1)/2=c` = `x^2+x-2*c=0` (using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)) to get the answer `x`.

Comment: The question is a little unclear, but shouldn't `sample(n,1,,1:n)` work?

Comment: @Giuseppe - That was my original (now-deleted) answer, but it doesn't run in constant expected time.  It takes much longer to run for large values of n, presumably due to the extra work of weighted sampling from bigger-and-bigger  vectors...

Comment: @Giuseppe - [try it](https://tio.run/##lc7BDoIwDAbg@56iiZctISLeJOFhxqhShUrWLpGnx82DXLzYW5t//7e4RY3UbdfEQenJlp34eZnQctVUVdOy2w4QRgwP0BFhIMn5PpUsJCG@QXPKA6QYfbmK4e5iqPucjfo@d4lflmm1TUvVF7q7ImfPudpSLWm2RXPG7J7X3AsxsQAxhFyunhXwtWBQHEBpxsydjayiOB/L/hOjHcv58rW/nmxv)

Comment: ah, I didn't test that. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｉ⌊⁺·⁵₂⊕‽Ｘ⁺·⁵Ｎ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0nP79IIyCntFjDQM9URyG4sDSxKDUoP79EwzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFIygxLyU/VyMgvzwVWbVnXkFpiV9pbhJQVFNTR8FIEwqs//83@a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
            Ｎ   Input `n` as a number
         ⁺·⁵    Plus literal number `0.5`
        Ｘ    ²  Squared
       ‽        Random element of implicit range
      ⊕         Incremented
    ₂           Square root
  ⁺·⁵           Plus literal number `0.5`
 ⌊              Floor
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Example: For `n=4`, the implicit range is `[0..20)`, which the remaining code maps `0..1` to `1`, `2..5` to `2`, `6..11` to `3` and `12..19` to `4`, thus `p(k)∝k` as desired.

Comment: Neil - does sampling from a range execute in constant time in Charcoal for all range sizes?  In R, for instance, it's slower to sample from a big range than from a small one... [try it in R](https://tio.run/##K/r//7@yQkZ@uUJOfl66Qkm@QnFibkFOqkJaUX6uQqJCcW5iTo5CWWpySX6RPVdxZXFJaq5eSWZuqgZEnYahgY6hAQTohGhqcuEzLCkzHa9RqWiG/QcA)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Certainly Charcoal calls the underlying API in constant time...

Comment: I also tried to port your approach, and I'm having difficulty (but maybe I just don't understand the explanation...).  You explain: "```12..19``` maps to ```4```", but I calculate that ```floor(sqrt(12 + 1.5))``` is equal to ```3```.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Whoops, somehow I conflated the `floor(sqrt(12+1)+0.5)` into a `floor(sqrt(12+1.5))`... fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 71 bytes

```python
lambda x:x-abs((a:=r(x)-r(x+1))+(a>=0))
from random import*
r=randrange
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5BDoIwEEXXcoouZ0SMLDSEpG5ceAhlUUvRRmhJWxK4gJdwQ2L0Tt7GChgXM_9n8vIy91fduYtW_aOgx2fjiih570tWnXJG2rSN2MkCsJQaaDHyK4wRI2DbbYIYFEZXxDCV-5BVrY2bB4Z-D37OYtLdBozrshTcSa3sxJKdbpQTJuCE_jp4qTZEEqnI4ADbVDC2DeI8Xq0wDWb8UMAas5DGf9x6pciBL6-is4BfrDZSOZALfpAZjt_0_Zgf)

Surprisingly tricky. Uses the fact that the sum of 2 numbers form a rectangle, then using `a>=0` to add 1 to negative numbers then abs merges both halves of the triangle.

Comment: It seems like your explanation is out of date?

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
f(n){n=sqrt(2*(rand()/21e8*n*++n/2)+1)-.5;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BbsMgEEX3nGLkKg2YOMZIkaK6uYI3WVZeuNikRAlpwVUXlq9eisGt3EVmM8yf/x8jspMQzkmsyaAP9sP0mKfYNLrFJOdFt091SqnOOaEFyba7cnQPbSeV7qACztDvcISChUJI6R6ujdJYETQg8GUD71GRMoyT4VVp@1LVcIBhjKq8GcDTSnmRlb49w9E3SknYTxVSElekprREd2PVIjb8hd@Nt0mcrBhvvXfFdu0TJBtQm8hV9XzfP@w5Ys8eO7sgjy9We3l5XfzlsxdvjcHr7XqB86rFSTIrIxqR@xby0pysyy5Xl339AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 9 bytes

```
Đř⇹0⇹Ř×ʀ↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISjMx@17zQA4qMzDk8/1fCobeL//6YA)

Port of [@loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252568/113573)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 24 bytes

```
{Bag(1..*Z=>1..$_).pick}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2ikxXcNQT08rytYOSKnEa@oVZCZn1/7XK06sVEjLL1JI0zA00FSoqFAwNDD4DwA)

A `Bag` object is a set with multiplicity, and it has a `pick` method that returns a random key, where each key is weighted by its multiplicity in the bag.  Here it's initialized with a list of the numbers from 1 up to the input argument `$_`, each one weighted by itself.

- `1 .. *` is the infinite list of natural numbers.
- `1 .. $_` is the list of natural numbers from 1 up to the input argument.
- `Z=>` zips those two lists together with the pair creation operator `=>`.  It stops when it reaches the end of the shorter/noninfinite list, of course.